# ListView items do not display

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I have a rather simple `ListView` with `GridView` style. Cells are binded to some properties of an `ObservableCollection` elements. I have no idea why thaey are not displaying. I were thinking about implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a class of element contained by collection, but once an element is constructed and added to a collection it is never changed so it should be working just fine.

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<SceneElement> SceneObjects { get; set; }
...
SceneObjects.Add(new Camera());
SceneObjects.Add(new Cuboid(20, 30, 40));
```

`Camera` and `Cuboid` both inherit from `SceneObject` (`SceneObject` <- `Figure` <- `Cuboid` and `SceneObject` <- `Camera`)

XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                      DataContext="{Binding SceneObjects}"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <GridView x:Key="StyleOne">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="1" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="X: " />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" Y: " />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position.Y}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" Z: " />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position.Z}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ListView">
                        <Setter Property="View" Value="{StaticResource StyleOne}" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Style>
            </ListView>
```

`Position` property is defined inside an abstract `SceneElement` class.
`Position`'s `X`, `Y` and `Z` are properties as well.

**EDIT**

This has solved the issue:

```
private ObservableCollection<SceneElement> sceneObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<SceneElement> SceneObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return sceneObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            sceneObjects = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SceneObjects");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this was necessary? I've used `ObservableCollection` severeal time so far and it always worked without notifying.

Comment: You set the `ObservableCollection` as `DataContext`? I would set the VM containing the ObservableCollection as context and then binding the  `ItemSource` to  `SceneObjects`?

Comment: Binding `ItemSource` to `SceneObjects` and `DataContext` to VM is the same thing in my opinion. When you bind `DataContext` to `ObservableCollection` and then `ItemSource` just `{Binding}` it is binded to elements contained by this collection. I did it in the past and it worked.

Comment: nice learned somthing. thx

Comment: You still need to notify about the property being changed. hence PropertyChanged event. Observable collection will notify about changes but UI doesn't know that the property that was initially null now has items in it. Hop this makes sense.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Yes, it makes sense, but I once in the past did something similar without notifying `ObservableCollection` changed, and newly added elements did appear on a `ListView`. That's wierd but it seems it is better to notify just in case.

Comment: I know what I did - after any change I did this in C# code: `<list_view_name>.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection` and now it all is clear

Comment: That sounds like a code behind approach. You should steer clear from that. It will save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why your application wasn't displaying the information about the collection is because the UI wasn't aware of any changes.
Using `ObservableCollection` doesn't guarantee the results will be displayed if said collection is not initialized before it is used. As it is a plain property on the ViewModel it needs to notify if said object, in this case `ObservableCollection` has been changed, but not in the sense items inside of the collection.
This is due to the fact of **NOT** raising the `PropertyChanged` event for `SceneObjects`, which is crucial for `WPF` apps using `Bidning`.

Answer (score -2):

at the point where the wpf system attempts to create the binding, your observablecollection was null, as xamimax above said.

instantiate your observablecollection in your constructor, and later you can add the items and they will appear.

for example, the following works because i first instantiated the observable collection and then added items 5 seconds later.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.SceneObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
     Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((old) =>
     {
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
         {
             this.sceneObjects.Add(new MyClass("name"));
             this.sceneObjects.Add(new MyClass("name"));
         });
     });

     this.DataContext = this;
 }
```

and here is an example that doesnt work, because i instantiate the observable collection 5 secs after the wpf system tried to bind to it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((old) => { this.SceneObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyClass> { new MyClass("name"), new MyClass("name") }; });

        this.DataContext = this;
}
```

and as you already realized, you can throw propchanged to make wpf system display those items, but i do think you should simply instantiate the observablecollection earlier so that you dont need to throw propchanged later.

Comment: What does “throw propchanged” mean?

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged("SceneObjects");

Comment: Do you understand that nothing is throwing anything?

Comment: What does “throwing anything” mean? is "anything" an exception you 
developed? and what is "nothing"? can you provide your nothing.cs?

Comment: If you’re having trouble understanding the difference between throwing an exception and raising an event, you should read up on both. There are plenty of good C# primers out there. While we’re here, you shouldn’t be recommending `DataContext = this;`, either.

Comment: i am not recommending it, i am giving him the most simple example in attempt to clarify his problem. i looked up the difference between throwing an exception and raising an event again, and i still dont understand what you mean by "nothing is throwing anything". can you provide the code for nothing and anything?